# Compact representation of many ofstreams in C++11

Tags: c++11, ofstream

I'm writing a code that frequently uses file I/O.
I have to write 10 files and read vice versa.
The code is as follows:

```
ofstream of1("file1");
ofstream of2("file2");
ofstream of3("file3");
...
ofstream of10("file10");
```

It seems a messy code.
Is there any way to represent those in a compact format?

Comment: A common way would probably be pointers in a vector. Since C++11 we might be able to use instances, emplace and movement for the objects in the vector.

Comment: Do they have to be open at the same time?

Comment: @RSahu no. once written, usually one is to be closed.

Comment: In that case, it's not clear to me why you have ten variables of type `ofstream`.

Comment: Clarification needed: are those filenames arbitrary, or is that part of the problem and do you need a way to generate the filename pattern as well? It looks like a case for `std::array<std::ostream, 10> {{ "file1", ..."file10"}}`.